# Avoiding dead DIVs in an HTML grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The objective is to insert side margins for wider screens, while keeping the header span the entire width.

[image: side margins through dead DIVs]

Normally we'd write

```
.inner {
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

to get such margins, but it turns out that HTML grids are so flexible that they make side margins possible through dead grid DIVs.

But somehow using dead DIVs does not seem quite right. Is there a way to obtain side margins within a grid. I see how this can be done with a blend of `flex` and `grid`. Here I'm wondering if it can be done with grids alone.

```css
body {
    height: 100vh; margin: 0; display: flex;
}
.outer{
    margin: 5px; border: 5px; padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.inner {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 5px; border: 5px; padding: 5px; grid-gap: 5px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 5fr 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "side";
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .inner {
        grid-template-rows: 100px 6fr;
        grid-template-columns: 5fr 100px;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header"
            "content side";
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .inner {
        grid-template-rows:    100px 6fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 100px 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header header header"
            "leftmargin content side rightmargin";
    }
}
.box {
    padding: 10px; margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #444;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 150%;
    position: relative;
}
.header      { grid-area: header;  }
.content     { grid-area: content; }
.side        { grid-area: side;    }
.leftmargin  { grid-area: leftmargin; }
.rightmargin { grid-area: rightmargin; }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="box header">Header</div>
        <div class="box content">Content</div>
        <div class="box side">Side</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dots (`.`) to declare [empty grid areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas#Leaving_a_grid_cell_empty):

```
grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    ". content side .";
```

**Example:**

```css
body {
    height: 100vh; 
    margin: 10px;
}

.inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 5fr 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "side";
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .inner {
        grid-template-rows: 100px 6fr;
        grid-template-columns: 5fr 100px;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header"
            "content side";
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .inner {
        grid-template-rows:    100px 6fr;
        grid-template-columns: 5% 5fr 100px 5%;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header header header"
            ". content side .";
    }
}
.box {
    padding: 10px; margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #444;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 150%;
    position: relative;
}
.header      { grid-area: header;  }
.content     { grid-area: content; }
.side        { grid-area: side;    }
```

```html
<div class="inner">
    <div class="box header">Header</div>
    <div class="box content">Content</div>
    <div class="box side">Side</div>
</div>
```